# Java ObjectOutputStream/ObjectInputStream

Tags: java, kotlin, serializable

I'm trying to implement Serializable interface for my class and I have a field in it that is of Enum class type. What should I call to write this field do byte stream?

```
class SingleEntry() : Serializable {
    // Category is an Enum class
    var category = Category.FOOD
    ....
    private fun writeObject(output: java.io.ObjectOutputStream) {
        output.writeObject(category)
    }
}
```

writeUTF(), writeObject() or some other is used for this purpose?

Comment: Have you tried the code you've given?  If so, does it work, or does it given a compile or runtime error?

Comment: Use `writeObject`.  Enums are always serializable.

Comment: @LouisWasserman are you sure about enums always being serializable? At least in plain java an enum can have a nonserializable member. That way, the enum will not be effectively serializable.

Comment: By the way, I don't think using `Serializable` is recommended (at least in Java, I don't know about Kotlin). There are other alternatives, such as JSON.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help guys. I ended up having to switch away from the enum since I want to allow the user to add his own category. As far as I know enums can't be expanded in runtime.